# Obreon: screen reader doesn't read dropdown items

Tags: orbeon, screen-readers, wcag

NVDA Screen reader doesn't read items of dropdowns with search when user is hovering them or focusing them with Tab key. Instead it is reading the content of search field. Is it a known issue? Will that be changed in future releases?

Here is an trivial example:
https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/785b85a843a9910091915ecab6a12a83a8281cc9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, and unfortunately this is due to issue [#3735](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3735) of Select2, the component used by Orbeon Forms for the dropdowns with search. On the Orbeon Forms side, this is tracked as issue [#4854](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4854).